# What are some pairs of mathematically-important functions that differ only at a few points?

Tags: big-list

Examples would include things like

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
x^y & \text{ if } (x, y) \neq 0 \\
0 & \text{ else} \end{cases}$$

versus

$$g(x, y) = \begin{cases}
x^y & \text{ if } (x, y) \neq 0 \\
1 & \text{ else} \end{cases}$$

both of which have their uses; or $n \mapsto H_n(X)$ versus $n \mapsto \tilde{H}_n(X)$ in algebraic topology.

Comment: Can a few also be infinitely many, but zero density?

Comment: Sure, so long as it's relevant to the spirit of the question.  (A bad answer would be something where you have two functions with finite domain that have no particular relation to each other, for instance.)

Comment: Then let's get this out of the way: $\lceil x\rceil$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor+1$

Answer (score 1):

How about the Liouville function, $$\lambda(n)=(-1)^{\Omega(n)},$$ versus the Möbius function, defined as $$\mu(n) = \begin{cases} (-1)^{\Omega(n)} && n \text{ is squarefree} \\ 0 && n \text{ is not squarefree} \end{cases}$$

($n$ is the product of $\Omega(n)$ primes.)

They differ on infinitely many points, but they are also the same on infinitely many points.